# SQL Group Function and concatenation

Tags: sql

I need to rename the minimum salary as the lowest and the maximum as the highest and then I need to concatenate the department_id ' with a job_id of ' job_id.

I keep getting errors when I try to use the group by function and when I add parenthesis it has missing brackets. My input is below. Please help meeeee

```
SELECT MIN (SALARY) AS "LOWEST SALARY", MAX (SALARY) AS "HIGHEST SALARY", DEPARTMENT_ID||' with a job_id of '||JOB_ID AS "Records"
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY JOB_ID;
```

I keep getting errors and that it cant group. The output should be something like this:

```
Lowest Salary   Highest Salary   Records
-------------------      ----------------------     ---------------- 
200                5000                 50 with a job_Id of It_pres
450                7000                 65 with a job_id of mg_clerk
.
.
.
14 rows selected
```

THANK YOUUUU

Comment: your department id has to be in the group as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The department ID has to be in the grouping because its in your select as a standard field.

```
SELECT MIN (SALARY) AS "LOWEST SALARY", MAX (SALARY) AS "HIGHEST SALARY", DEPARTMENT_ID||' with a job_id of '||JOB_ID AS "Records"
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID;
```